# Unable to add new node in jsTree

Tags: javascript, html, jstree

I am trying to add a new node to a jsTree block, but somehow my code is not working. I have already tried everything I could but still have not found any solution to why it is not working.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jsTree test</title>
  <!-- 2 load the theme CSS file -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/themes/default/style.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <!-- 3 setup a container element -->
  <div id="jstree">
    <!-- in this example the tree is populated from inline HTML -->
    <ul>
      <li>Root node 1
        <ul>
          <li id="child_node_1">Child node 1</li>
          <li>Child node 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Root node 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button onclick="addLeaf()">Add Leaf</button>

  <!-- 4 include the jQuery library -->
  <script src="jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- 5 include the minified jstree source -->
    <script src="dist/jstree.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function () {
    // 6 create an instance when the DOM is ready
    $('#jstree').jstree();
  });
  </script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function addLeaf() {


  var position = 'inside';
  var parent = $('#jstree').jstree('get_selected');
  var newNode = { state: "open", data: "mydata" };

  $('#jstree').jstree("create_node", parent, position, newNode, false, false);

}
```

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? And URL of the widget you are using..

Comment: @RayonDabre here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yz34go3u/

Comment: `addLeaf is not defined`...console...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3q9Ma/223/ will help

Comment: @RayonDabre Cannot see anything happening in that fiddle. I have updated mine that I sent previously. https://jsfiddle.net/yz34go3u/1/

Comment: I saw everything happening in that fiddle...Help yourself mate!